# d3.js selection conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using the d3js join model, is it possible to do conditional rendering based on the data content?

I want to do something like this:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll('.node').data(nodes);

var node = nodes.enter().insert('svg:g').attr('class', 'node');

// if node.hasDuration {
   node.insert('svg:rect');
//} else {
   node.insert('svg:circle');
//}

nodes.exit().remove();
```

There doesn't seem to be a way using the join model (enter/exit) to have conditional rendering.  I can brute force it with selection.each() but that seems to defeat the purpose of the selection model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter):

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll('.node').data(nodes);

nodes.enter()
  .insert('svg:g')
  .attr('class', 'node');

nodes.filter(function(d,i){
  return d.hasDuration;
}).append('svg:rect');

nodes.filter(function(d,i){
  return !d.hasDuration;
}).append('svg:circle');
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gp2i8eIm03mEb1cq89V4?p=preview).

Comment: Perfect!  Don't know how I missed that in the documentation.  Thanks!