# d3.js: conditional rendering of nodes (don't render some nodes)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) and would like to know if conditional rendering can be applied. 
For example: Draw all the nodes their names start with **a** or has a child starts with **a** and do not render the reset.
[image]

---

Obvious solution would be changing the JSON but maybe using [filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_filter), which I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415005/d3-js-selection-conditional-rendering) question, but my question is: how to skip rendering of a node which doesn't match the condition.
**Note**: There other nodes which need to be rendering in the image above.

Comment: Not sure what I missed here, as you already stated - 'You can filter the JSON before you feed it to the .data() of SVG'

Comment: Your code here would be useful, to see where you are at with this... Can you provide us with the piece that is not working as expected?

Comment: If you can modify this code to show the required result: http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033, then it will solve my question.